# How to find complementary rows in matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1
 [5,]    1    1    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    1    1
 [7,]    1    0    1    0
 [8,]    0    1    0    1
 [9,]    1    1    1    1
```

So, there are some rows that are complementary. In this matrix these are:

```
[5,]    1    1    0    0
[6,]    0    0    1    1
```

and

```
[7,]    1    0    1    0
[8,]    0    1    0    1
```

What I want to do is to find these complementary rows and keep just the first one of them. The expected output should be this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    1    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    1    0
 [4,]    0    0    0    1
 [5,]    1    1    0    0
 [6,]    1    0    1    0
 [7,]    1    1    1    1
```

Is there a way to do this in R?

Comment: Can you please show your expected output?

Comment: Check the answers below.

Comment: No - I mean it would help others to see your expected output. You don't provide it and neither does the accepted answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your matrix is called `m`:

```
# find duplicate rows
dists <- as.matrix(dist(m, method = "manhattan"))
equals <- which(dists == ncol(m), arr.ind = TRUE, useNames = FALSE)

# remove symmetry (5,6 == 6,5)
equals <- equals[equals[,1] < equals[,2],]
to_drop <- equals[,2]

m <- m[-to_drop,]
```

This uses the Manhattan distance to find rows for which the sum of the differences equals the number of columns, hence all elements are different.

Answer (score 2):

In base-R is all that is needed to run this code.

Sample data:

```
mydata<- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1),ncol=4)
```

Code

```
i=1
while(i <= nrow(mydata)){
  test <- matrix(rep(mydata[i,],nrow(mydata)),nrow=nrow(mydata),byrow=T)+mydata
  RowsToRemove <- grep(1,sapply(1:nrow(mydata),function(x) prod(test[x,]==1)))
  if(length(RowsToRemove)!=0){
    mydata <- mydata[-RowsToRemove,]
  }
  i=i+1
}
```

Output

```
> mydata
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1
[5,]    1    1    0    0
[6,]    1    0    1    0
[7,]    1    1    1    1
```

Answer (score 0):

**using `xor()`:**

```
complements <- mapply(function(x,y) { all(xor(mat[x,], mat[y,]))}, x = 1:(nrow(mat)-1), y = 2:nrow(mat) )
names(complements) <- paste(x = 1:(nrow(mat)-1), y = 2:nrow(mat), sep = '')
complements
#    12    23    34    45    56    67    78    89 
# FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

**Extract first row of the match:**

```
mat[(1:(nrow(mat)-1))[complements], ]
#      V1 V2 V3 V4
# [1,]  1  1  0  0
# [2,]  1  0  1  0
```

**Extract second row of the match:**

```
mat[(2:nrow(mat))[complements], ]
#      V1 V2 V3 V4
# [1,]  0  0  1  1
# [2,]  0  1  0  1
```

**EDIT:**

After OP edited the expected output, the code is given below.

The edge case of non-complementarity with row-1 and row-2 is taken care first and then the entire matrix is checked for complements.

```
ind <- unique( c(unlist( ifelse( all(xor(mat[1, ], mat[2, ])), 1, list(c(1,2)))),
                 mapply(function(x,y) { ifelse(all(xor(mat[x,], mat[y,])), x, y)}, x = 1:(nrow(mat)-1), y = 2:nrow(mat) )))
mat[ind, ]
#      V1 V2 V3 V4
# [1,]  1  0  0  0
# [2,]  0  1  0  0
# [3,]  0  0  1  0
# [4,]  0  0  0  1
# [5,]  1  1  0  0
# [6,]  1  0  1  0
# [7,]  1  1  1  1
```

**Data:**

```
mat <- structure(c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L), .Dim = c(9L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4")))
```

Comment: someone downvoted my answer without recognizing that OP edited question later with the expected output.